# React - Sharing a function across multiple components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my Application, I have the following function `handleDeleteMessage`  which essentially interacts with a database and the backend.

```
    const handleDeleteMessage = async (messageId) => {
        // removeMessage is a function that interacts with my backend database
        await removeMessage(chatId, messageId, userData.userId)
        return
    })
```

Currently, the function `handleDeleteMessage` is located inside my **Chat** Component, which has a child component that also requires this function. Currently, I pass `handleDeleteMessage` as a `prop` to my child component, however I was wondering whether there is a way to define this function once, and then use it in multiple components, including child components. This would remove the need to add the function as a prop to each child requiring the function.

Also note that ChatId, which is a parameter of the function, is a part of Chat component's local state (Chat component is the parent), therefore this is why I don't simply export and import the function.

I found **react context**, however this seems to be only for sharing global react `state` and not for sharing general functions such as `handleDeleteMessage` which isn't classed as state. Any potential solutions? Thanks.

Comment: Any reason you just don't `export` and `import`?

Comment: @Keith Yes because this function requires a **chatId** parameter which comes from the **chat component's** local state. Also note ChatComponent is the parent in this situation

Comment: You can bind functions, but your idea of a `context` also works fine.  If you have a function that depends on a closure over some state, it's actually a good way of doing it.

Comment: @Keith Hi, I don't quite understand what you mean. How could I use a `context` in this situation? I would define the function in the global `context`, however what about the chatId `state` variable which is a parameter to the function, but is only available as a part of the Parent component's local state.

Comment: Well if your currently passing as a prop, you do it the same way.  A Context is like been able to pass props down to all children.

Comment: you can export handleDeleteMessage and import where it's required. For chatId you can store it in context and pass it to handleDeleteMessage as a param.

Comment: @Keith So `context` api allows you to define and consume functions, which are completely unrelated to react `state`? And then after defining this regular function in context, you would pass chatId (which is a state variable) as a parameter wherever you call this function . Is this information correct, as I believed `context` was only for sharing global react `state` between components

Comment: I use it to also bind functions, Javascript closures are one of it's most alluring features.   eg. for me `ctx.removeMessage(ctx.messageId)` is way nicer than `ctx.removeMessage(ctx.chatID, ctx.messageID, ctx.userID)`

Comment: `completely unrelated to react state`,  No not if your using a closure, it's totally related to the state if you want it to be.  You can also store the `state` in the `context` if you want.

Comment: mmm, I wonder if knocking up a demo might be useful?.

Comment: @Keith That looks extremely clean. However if using `ctx.removeMessage(ctx.messageId)`, where would I retrieve the  `chatID`, `messageID` and `userId` parameters from? Are you saying to store these parameters in local components, like I currently do,  instead of in `context`?

Comment: If using a closure, `removeMessage` will implicitly have the `chatID`, if you give us a few mins I'll see if I can knock something up that simple, but makes sense.

Comment: @Herbadams or can also just use a useHook (basically like a component without the rendering part) in there you can also handle state and maybe returning another function could also be something you want. Many options. Also the react context is not global, the scope is only passed downwards not upwards in the JSX shadow dom.

Comment: @F.Müller  if I added the function to a context (note the function is a regular function completely irrelevant to state), would I just pass in the ChatID as a parameter to the function, or add chat id as a context state variable itself? As stated, chat id (which is a parameter to the function) is a local state variable of the parent. Thanks

Comment: @Herbadams not sure I get what you are asking but I guess it depends on what you want to achieve. If the id is constant (imagine a constructor or a constant value) then maybe state, if it is dynamic as an argument. If you want to do more with the id ... maybe add a getter or something you may want it to be a state. If it can be garbage collected after you call the function, use it as an argument.

Comment: @F.Müller Well chat id is dynamic, depending on the current chat on screen, it’s a parameter to the deletemessage function, which I will store in a context. My question is how do I handle passing this chatId parameter. Would I leave it in local state of the parent where it currently is, or move it into context? Note chatId could potentially be needed by child components as well as the parent. But ultimately chatId is currently a state variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Context to pass function, especially if used with closures is a really nice way of passing functions to children.

Below I've created a really simple example, were we have 2 pretend chat windows, the `ChatScreen` component creates a Context, it stores both the Props & a function that has a closure over the `chatID`, this means you don't need to pass the `chatID` to the `deleteMessage`, so when you click the `Delete Message` button you will notice it knows what `chatID` it refers too.

```js
const ChatContext = React.createContext();


function ChatHeader() {
  const {chatID} = React.useContext(ChatContext);
  return <h1>Chat Header for: {chatID}</h1>
}

function ChatBody() {
  const {chatID, deleteMessage} = React.useContext(ChatContext);
  return <div>
    ChatBody for {chatID}
    <button onClick={() => deleteMessage('delete')}>Delete Message</button>
  </div>
}

function ChatScreen(props) {
  function deleteMessage(msg) {
    console.log(`Delete message ${msg} for ${props.chatID}`);
  }
  return <div>
    <ChatContext.Provider value={{
      ...props,
      deleteMessage
    }}>
      <ChatHeader/>
      <ChatBody/>
    </ChatContext.Provider>
  </div>
}

const App = () => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <ChatScreen chatID="chat1"/>
          <ChatScreen chatID="chat2"/>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: @Herbadams  Your welcome, I think contexts are a really useful feature of React, and can really help keep components clean, I find it help prevent `props of doom`, were you are constantly passing prop to child to child to child,etc.. :)

Comment: that was exactly my issue, I was passing props everywhere. With context, I define the chatid, and the deletemessage function, and then wherever it needs to be used, I only pass in message id. Fantastic way to handle this issue

Comment: @Herbadams  Indeed, I was the same, I found myself passing Props to child that never even use said prop, is was only send because the child of a child required it.  My code these days look way cleaner, basically a Component only takes a props if it uses it, and when you think about it, that just makes total sense..